# Установка grab на Windows python 3.5

Tags: python, grab

Как установить фрэймворк Grab на Windows 10 для Python 3.5?

Прошу подробной инструкции с указанием **директорий** для распаковки файлов и пояснений по поводу того, в **какое именно окно** вписывать команды по установке.
Пробовал в Shell, python.exe и cmd.

UPD.
При запуске стандартного теста **runtest.py** из корневой папки grab выдается ошибка:

```
grab\test\util.py, line 5, from test_server import TestServer no module named 'test_server'
```

Comment: `Гуглил, все мои попытки установить что-либо не увенчались успехом`. Расскажите подробно, что вы пытались сделать и какой результат получили? А то вдруг мы будем терять время, предлагая вам сделать то же самое.

Comment: Но вообще `pip install mypackagename` должно работать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовали?

1. Устанавливаете `python`, `pip`.
2. Запускаете `cmd.exe`.
3. Командой `path/to/your/pip-installation/pip.exe install grab` (вставьте свои соответствующие пути) устанавливаете `grab`.

Например, на *Windows 7*, которая оказалась рядом, сделано так:
`C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install grab`

P.S.: как было сказано выше, более *цивилизованным* способом является редактирование переменной `PATH`.

Comment: Сделал примерно так же, только в командной строке использовал команду chdir для смены папки. Но возникли новые проблемы. Первым делом решил обновить pip, но выскочила ошибка доступа, хотя я админ. Переустановил Пайтон в другое место, но теперь выскочила ошибка при установке LXML: 'unable to find vcvarsall.bat'

Comment: @pachvo Не нужно было переустанавливать что-то, потому что у вас не было доступа, это плохой способ. Надо было сначала разобраться в одной проблеме, а не порождать новые. Ошибка `LXML: 'unable to find vcvarsall.bat'` говорит о том, что `pip`,  не может найти компилятор, `Microsoft Visual C++`, скорей всего. Он у вас установлен?

Comment: @pachvo почитайте ответы [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830942/pip-install-gives-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) с похожей проблемой, хотя бы для ознакомления, что происходит.

Comment: полагаю нет. Установил Visual Studio 2015, в нем же должно быть. Но в нём, как я понимаю нет pip

Comment: @pachvo Некоторые модули `python` собираются `pip`ом из исходных текстов, для этого необходим компилятор. Если его нет, соответственно `pip` не может установить модуль и ругается. Теперь пробуйте установить то, что хотели, с  помощью `pip`.  Вообще, если устанавливать `python` и `pip` штатным образом, то всё без костылей должно работать.

Comment: Переустановил VS, добавил галочку при установке на "Microsoft Visual C++". Теперь при установке lxml в pip появляется ошибка: fatal error c1083 не удается открыть файл включение libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory    command 'C:\\Program files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: @pachvo пробовали что-то другое с помощью `pip` установить, помимо  `lxml`? И перезагружались, когда Windows этого хотела? Она порой без этого не может.

Comment: Обновил pip через него самого же и установил pycurl. Винда не просила перезагрузок, но несколько раз я перезагружался уже

Comment: Установил wheel и с его помощью установил lxml отсюда: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml Grab тоже установился, но при запуске теста выдаёт ошибку: text\util.py, line 5, from test_server import TestServer no module named 'test_server'

Comment: @pachvo да, бинарный `wheel` может быть решением проблем, связанных с собиранием модулей из исходников на Windows. по поводу `text\util.py, line 5, from test_server import TestServer no module named 'test_server'`: опишите подробней, что происходит, что именно запускается (можете добавить в свой вопрос). Я так понимаю, вы запускаете какой-то пример или [что-то похожее](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/test-server)?

Comment: да, именно. Произвёл pip install test-server и заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

#### Решение через редактирование переменной окружения PATH.

Запускаете `cmd` и пишите `pip install grab`.

Если `pip` не находит, в переменных путях в `PATH` добавьте путь к папке с питоном, например: `C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;`.

После этого нужно перезапустить `cmd` (если запускаете через `IDE`, то и ее тоже) и повторить команду, если пути до `pip.exe` указаны верно, заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через [Thonny](https://thonny.org/) (именно оболочке), команда может быть такой: pip3 install [grab](https://pypi.org/project/grab/).
в python есть компилятор IDEL в нём тоже можно попробовать, если не какой из этих вариантов не подошёл попробуй обновится или [Windows 8.1](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/windows8ISO) или [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10).

Comment: Теоретически можно попробовать, только не через оболочку (консоль в нижней части ока), т.к. это интерактивный режим интерпретатора python, в котором команда  `pip3 install grab` вызовет ошибку синтаксиса, а через меню Инструменты - Управление пакетами.

Comment: через Инструменты -> открыть системную оболочку... там введи `pip3 install grab` если в ошибке будет команда в ' ' выдели скопируй и туда же вставь

Comment: Это все опишите в ответе. Сейчас такое в ответе написано так, как будто команду нужно в консоли внизу окна запускать.

Comment: я не помню какую команду но она может быть в предупреждении, если там нет текста в кавычках то я не чем не помогу